# IllegalStateException when trying to commit fragment transaction?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am getting IllegalStateException when trying to commit a fragment transaction. The error is "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState". Now I know that I should wait to perform these transactions until the activity calls onResumeFragments. The crash occurs after the activity has been backgrounded and then resumed when I click a button to change fragments. I can wait 10 seconds and it will still crash. When the activity resumes after a home screen press the old fragment is reloaded and works as expected. The crash occurs when the users clicks a button which will run the code below. The crash is at the commit() call. Any idea what would be causing this?

Code to change fragments:

```
private void changeFragment(MyRoboFragment frag, boolean allowStateLoss) {
    String fragName = frag.getClass().getName();

    if (fragName.equals(currentFragmentName)) return;

    currentFragmentName = fragName;

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragMan.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.base_fragment, frag);

    if (frag.pushToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }

    if (allowStateLoss == true) {
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } else {
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I have run into this error, it is because I am trying to work 
with a fragment that is no longer part of the activity (e.g., has been 
replaced).

Comment: The fragment that is being passed in is created every time using the empty constructor. Could this be related to onSaveInstance state screwing with the fragment it automatically restores?

Comment: I'd always call transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

Comment: See ww.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html